# Easiest way to vertically align, horizontally aligned images?

Tags: html, css

What is the easiest, quickest way to vertically align differently sized horizontally aligned images? Everything on Google is not working for me or I'm not doing it right... I've tried using the 'vertical-align' property in .media and .media img.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C8DKc/

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="avatar">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GgxBXAA.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="media">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GmT37TG.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
background-color: #e5e5e5;

}

#main {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    background-color: red;
}

#avatar {
    display: inherit;
}

.media {
    display: inherit;
}

.media img {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Might have something to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2744005/2191572 but JoshC's answer looks spot-on! Normally a vertical align is used in the context of a `<td>` so you need to have your `<div>` imitate a `<td>` through the use of `display:table-cell;`. At least this is the easiest way =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the parent, `#main`, to `display:table-cell`.

```
#main {
    padding: 10px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Then add `vertical-align:middle` to `.media` [**(working example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/T9H5L/)

```
.media {
    display: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to vertically align:

***HTML***

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="avatar" class="inner">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GgxBXAA.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="media inner">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GmT37TG.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
body {
background-color: #e5e5e5;

}

#main {
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    background-color: red;

}

#avatar {
    display: inherit;
}

.media {
    display: inherit;
}

.media img {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.inner{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

***Fiddle***
http://jsfiddle.net/6KJvj/

Comment: It looks like you just copied everything from my example -.-

Comment: @JoshC My fault, I copied the wrong jsFiddle window :(  Updated my code

Answer (score 0):

You use display:block. Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/C8DKc/

```
body {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

#main {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#avatar {
    display: inherit;
}

.media {
    display: inherit;
}

.media img {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```